# Coldfusion ArraySet() v. user defined cffunction

Tags: coldfusion

I replaced this user-defined CF function that I found.

```
<cffunction name="initializeValues" returntype="array" output="false">
<!--- Initialize all elements of an array to zero --->
  <cfargument name="inArray" required="yes" type="array">
  <cfargument name="inCount" required="yes" type="numeric">

  <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#inCount#">
    <cfset inArray[i] = 0>
  </cfloop>

  <cfreturn inArray>
</cffunction>
```

with the built-in CF9 function

```
ArraySet(arrayName, startingIndex, endingIndex, 0)
```

however, the final results differed somehow and threw an exception on the user page.

How do these functions differ?

Comment: They appear to do the same thing. Have you tried `cfdump`ing the resulting arrays and comparing them to see where it might be going wrong?

Comment: I have created the cfdump but have not run it yet. M

Comment: You need to tell us in what way the results different and also what the error was. It's a bit hard for us to help you, otherwise. Aside: you really ought to `var` that `i` variable in your function.

Comment: since I was assigning the return value of ArraySet() and then later trying to access it as an array, when it was changed to a BOOL, that was my problem.  The cfloop there was not mine original, and as a rule of thumb I agree with intializing variables before use; must come from my C++ background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide more specifics. What do you mean by "differed somehow" and what exception was thrown?

Without knowing more, one primary difference is that `ArraySet` modifies the array "in place".  Whereas the `cffunction` does not. With udf's arrays are passed "by value", so the function has no effect on the original array object. Instead you must capture the returned array. (Of course, then it does not make any sense to require an array argument in the first place, but .. that is a different topic.)

```
    arr = initializeValues([], 10);
    writeDump(arr);
```

Since `ArraySet` modifies the array in place, it returns true/false. Perhaps you are mistakenly capturing the result of `ArraySet` and overwriting your array object?

```
    // wrong: overwrites the array
    arr = [];
    arr = ArraySet(arr, 1, 10, 0);
    writeDump(arr); 

    // correct 
    arr = [];
    ArraySet(arr, 1, 10, 0);
    writeDump(arr);
```

Comment: I'm sure that is the exact logic problem that created with this quick replacement. I would have offered my details about the results, but unfortunately I just won't have access to them until Tuesday.